# Having trouble grabbing value of select tag with dropdown

Tags: javascript, select, click, fabricjs, addeventlistener

i've been using FabricJS for a couple days now, and i'm having trouble grabbing the value of my dropdown menu so I can properly apply the desired shape with an eventlistener of "click. So when I hit the dropdown menu and select "rectangle" and hit the button, it should generate a rectangle. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
   <p>Choose a Shape</p>

<select id="shapesId">
    <option value="square">Square</option>
    <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="triangle">Triangle</option>
    <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="polygon">Polygon</option>
    <option value="ellipse">Ellipse</option>
    <option value="line">Line</option>
</select>

<button id="realShapes">Go!</button>
```

so when we hit "Go!" I want to get the value of whatever is selected through the option of shapes.
And now here is my Javascript:

```
const shapes = document.getElementById("shapesId");
const e = shapes.value;
const clickShapes = document.getElementById("realShapes");
clickShapes.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
    if(e === "Rectangle") {
      const rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill: 'black',
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        angle: 45
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
    }
    
    canvas.renderAll();
})
```

I am so lost right now,and been trying to figure this out for hours, any help would be appreciated. Thank you to whoever is reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this to get the shapesid selected value (will store the value to xvalue) :

```
var xvalue  = document.getElementById("shapesId").options[document.getElementById("shapesId").selectedIndex].value;
```

Additional Information (you may use the following as a workable example):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #ff0000;">
</canvas>

<br>

<p>Choose a Shape</p>

<select id="shapesId">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="rectangle">rectangle</option>
    <option value="circle">circle</option>
</select>

<input type=button value="DRAW" onclick="javascript:draw();">





<script>

function draw() {

var xvalue  = document.getElementById("shapesId").options[document.getElementById("shapesId").selectedIndex].value;

if (xvalue=="rectangle")  {

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);


var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
}

if (xvalue=="circle")  {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
}
}


</script>
```

Comment: awesome, seems to work a little bit. It's giving me all rectangles in the output. even when i choose circle it will pop-out a rectangle. i had even added the code to generate a circle but it's still giving me nothing but rectangles :/

Comment: trying changing === "Rectangle" to == "rectangle"  (use ==, and also use r instead of R because your select box is using r as value)

Comment: still nothing :/ i tried changing to "==" and R to r but still doesn't work

Comment: aghhh you're the hero

Comment: Please see and try "Additional Information" in my answer. Thanks

Comment: thank you Ken! i'm trying to convert this code in Fabric, so i added an onclick function and added the function in the js file. is onClick better to use than addeventlistener? BTW it doesn't seem to be working still. i think i'm doing something wrong on my end...

Comment: Both onclick and addevenlistener (or just use onchange) should work. Please change to use fabric.js (use a step-by-step approach) and you may be able to do the conversion soon.

Comment: awesome, i'll keep you updated! (assuming you care enough) xD thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Great ! Have a nice day. (please mark this post as answered so that we can close it)